# Get specific data from csv file

Tags: php, regex, csv

I have a csv file and I want to retrieve only the following fields:

```
mobile=0786066486&phone_num=&mob_phone_num=6066486
```

As an example how my file looks like:

```
LeadID,ClientID,res,Name,Phone,Email,Serial,Time,Comment,Address,wasSent,Promocode,custDetails,DynamicSerialParams
7276199,B6FBEEBF-FE33-42D3-B0B8-83BF44F3C192,NULL,محمد ابوالرب,-786065524,king_moneer45@yahoo.com,339863,30/06/2014 00:00,<additional><pageName type='text'>masterLP - overnight96NDH5</pageName><FName type='text'>محمد</FName><LName type='text'>ابوالرب</LName><Mobile type='text'>0786066486</Mobile><Country type='text'>Jordan</Country><SendEmails>true</SendEmails><IP>91.186.228.92</IP><CountryID>107</CountryID><Language>Arabic</Language><source>zomztest</source></additional>,Jordan,1,b3b9ffe9-9301-4bd2-932f-cfab2f0f61d1,<OperatingSystem>Windows NT 6.1</OperatingSystem><UserLang>ar</UserLang><Browser>Chrome</Browser><BrowserVersion>Chrome 35.0.1916.153</BrowserVersion><Refferer>http://www.zomztest.ae/landing_pages/br1/ar/overnight96NDH5/?content=overnight96NDH5&dsp9=uae-t.com&dsp8=البورصة&dsp1=&SID=339863&gclid=CNmkp5KloL8CFcbKtAodk3gAag</Refferer><Url>http://l.zomztest.com/lead.ashx?fname=محمد&lname=ابوالرب&country=JO&email=king_moneer45@yahoo.com&phone=0786066486&sendmails=true&mobile=0786066486&phone_num=&mob_phone_num=6066486&area_code=&mob_area_code=078&cat=masterLP&promocode=&SID=339863&clang=AE&content=overnight96NDH5&gclid=CNmkp5KloL8CFcbKtAodk3gAag&dsp8=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%B5%D8%A9&dsp9=uae-t.com</Url><IP>91.186.228.92</IP>,dsp1=&dsp2=&dsp3=&dsp4=&dsp5=&dsp6=&dsp7=&dsp8=البورصة&dsp9=uae-t.com&dsp10=&dsp11=&dsp12=&dsp13=&dsp14=&dsp15=
7276199,B6FBEEBF-FE33-42D3-B0B8-83BF44F3C192,NULL,محمد ابوالرب,-786065524,king_moneer45@yahoo.com,339863,30/06/2014 00:00,<additional><pageName type='text'>masterLP - overnight96NDH5</pageName><FName type='text'>محمد</FName><LName type='text'>ابوالرب</LName><Mobile type='text'>0786066486</Mobile><Country type='text'>Jordan</Country><SendEmails>true</SendEmails><IP>91.186.228.92</IP><CountryID>107</CountryID><Language>Arabic</Language><source>zomztest</source></additional>,Jordan,1,b3b9ffe9-9301-4bd2-932f-cfab2f0f61d1,<OperatingSystem>Windows NT 6.1</OperatingSystem><UserLang>ar</UserLang><Browser>Chrome</Browser><BrowserVersion>Chrome 35.0.1916.153</BrowserVersion><Refferer>http://www.zomztest.ae/landing_pages/br1/ar/overnight96NDH5/?content=overnight96NDH5&dsp9=uae-t.com&dsp8=البورصة&dsp1=&SID=339863&gclid=CNmkp5KloL8CFcbKtAodk3gAag</Refferer><Url>http://l.zomztest.com/lead.ashx?fname=محمد&lname=ابوالرب&country=JO&email=king_moneer45@yahoo.com&phone=0786066486&sendmails=true&mobile=0786066486&phone_num=&mob_phone_num=6066486&area_code=&mob_area_code=078&cat=masterLP&promocode=&SID=339863&clang=AE&content=overnight96NDH5&gclid=CNmkp5KloL8CFcbKtAodk3gAag&dsp8=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%B5%D8%A9&dsp9=uae-t.com</Url><IP>91.186.228.92</IP>,dsp1=&dsp2=&dsp3=&dsp4=&dsp5=&dsp6=&dsp7=&dsp8=البورصة&dsp9=uae-t.com&dsp10=&dsp11=&dsp12=&dsp13=&dsp14=&dsp15=
7276200,B6FBEEBF-FE33-42D3-B0B8-83BF44F3C192,NULL,jose miguel abad tirado,-73501424,marjos091111@hotmail.com,236455,30/06/2014 00:01,<additional><pageName type='text'>masterLP - Testimonials5NoTime</pageName><FName type='text'>jose miguel</FName><LName type='text'>abad tirado</LName><Mobile type='text'>073943026717</Mobile><Country type='text'>Peru</Country><SA>yes</SA><SendEmails>true</SendEmails><IP>190.237.62.93</IP><CountryID>166</CountryID><Language>Spanish</Language><source>zomztest</source></additional>,Peru,1,598fa0fa-b033-964e-e204-eed2f6188f9a,<OperatingSystem>Windows NT 6.2; WOW64</OperatingSystem><UserLang>es-419</UserLang><Browser>Chrome</Browser><BrowserVersion>Chrome 35.0.1916.153</BrowserVersion><Refferer>http://www.zomztest.es/emerp/landing/masterlp/nobanslp.aspx?content=Testimonials5NoTime&mailT=630&delay=1&SA=Yes&dsp9=www.empresores.com&dsp1=&SID=236455&gclid=CKT-xcmloL8CFc9j7AodmRoAOQ</Refferer><Url>http://l.zomztest.com/lead.ashx?fname=jose+miguel&lname=abad+tirado&country=PE&email=marjos091111@hotmail.com&phone=073501475&sendmails=true&mobile=073943026717&phone_num=501475&mob_phone_num=943026717&area_code=073&mob_area_code=073&cat=masterLP&promocode=598fa0fa-b033-964e-e204-eed2f6188f9a&SID=236455&clang=ES&content=Testimonials5NoTime&mailT=630&delay=1&SA=Yes&gclid=CKT-xcmloL8CFc9j7AodmRoAOQ&dsp1=&dsp2=&dsp3=&dsp4=&dsp5=&dsp6=&dsp7=&dsp8=&dsp9=www.empresores.com&dsp10=&dsp11=google&dsp12=adsense&dsp13=/foros/26083-importar-de-poco-chile-bolivia-paraguay.html&dsp14=&dsp15=www.empresores.com</Url><IP>190.237.62.93</IP>,dsp1=&dsp2=&dsp3=&dsp4=&dsp5=&dsp6=&dsp7=&dsp8=&dsp9=www.empresores.com&dsp10=&dsp11=google&dsp12=adsense&dsp13=/foros/26083-importar-de-poco-chile-bolivia-paraguay.html&dsp14=&dsp15=www.empresores.com
7276200,B6FBEEBF-FE33-42D3-B0B8-83BF44F3C192,NULL,jose miguel abad tirado,-73501424,marjos091111@hotmail.com,236455,30/06/2014 00:01,<additional><pageName type='text'>masterLP - Testimonials5NoTime</pageName><FName type='text'>jose miguel</FName><LName type='text'>abad tirado</LName><Mobile type='text'>073943026717</Mobile><Country type='text'>Peru</Country><SA>yes</SA><SendEmails>true</SendEmails><IP>190.237.62.93</IP><CountryID>166</CountryID><Language>Spanish</Language><source>zomztest</source></additional>,Peru,1,598fa0fa-b033-964e-e204-eed2f6188f9a,<OperatingSystem>Windows NT 6.2; WOW64</OperatingSystem><UserLang>es-419</UserLang><Browser>Chrome</Browser><BrowserVersion>Chrome 35.0.1916.153</BrowserVersion><Refferer>http://www.zomztest.es/emerp/landing/masterlp/nobanslp.aspx?content=Testimonials5NoTime&mailT=630&delay=1&SA=Yes&dsp9=www.empresores.com&dsp1=&SID=236455&gclid=CKT-xcmloL8CFc9j7AodmRoAOQ</Refferer><Url>http://l.zomztest.com/lead.ashx?fname=jose+miguel&lname=abad+tirado&country=PE&email=marjos091111@hotmail.com&phone=073501475&sendmails=true&mobile=073943026717&phone_num=501475&mob_phone_num=943026717&area_code=073&mob_area_code=073&cat=masterLP&promocode=598fa0fa-b033-964e-e204-eed2f6188f9a&SID=236455&clang=ES&content=Testimonials5NoTime&mailT=630&delay=1&SA=Yes&gclid=CKT-xcmloL8CFc9j7AodmRoAOQ&dsp1=&dsp2=&dsp3=&dsp4=&dsp5=&dsp6=&dsp7=&dsp8=&dsp9=www.empresores.com&dsp10=&dsp11=google&dsp12=adsense&dsp13=/foros/26083-importar-de-poco-chile-bolivia-paraguay.html&dsp14=&dsp15=www.empresores.com</Url><IP>190.237.62.93</IP>,dsp1=&dsp2=&dsp3=&dsp4=&dsp5=&dsp6=&dsp7=&dsp8=&dsp9=www.empresores.com&dsp10=&dsp11=google&dsp12=adsense&dsp13=/foros/26083-importar-de-poco-chile-bolivia-paraguay.html&dsp14=&dsp15=www.empresores.com
```

What kind of regex should I use?

Comment: I'm sure that those people appreciate you posting their information in plaintext on this site.

Comment: Better to use fgetcsv() and simply test the fields you want to check against the entries in the array, rather than try to use a regexp

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
mobile=(\d*)&phone_num=(\d*)&mob_phone_num=(\d*)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/fI1lX5/2)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [1113-1123] `0786066486`
2.  [1134-1134] ``
3.  [1149-1156] `6066486`
MATCH 2
1.  [2488-2498] `0786066486`
2.  [2509-2509] ``
3.  [2524-2531] `6066486`
MATCH 3
1.  [3946-3958] `073943026717`
2.  [3969-3975] `501475`
3.  [3990-3999] `943026717`
MATCH 4
1.  [5711-5723] `073943026717`
2.  [5734-5740] `501475`
3.  [5755-5764] `943026717`
```

Comment: u can send me msg email

karts22@gmx.com

i pay u for wirte me script?

Comment: `^^^` funniest comment I've seen on SO in a long time!! @Robi SO is not a code writing service, first learn regex. Make some attempts at trying different methods trying to solve your problem then post your troubleshooted question on SO. Easy how it works, eh??

Comment: @Robi No need to pay, we can help you. If you go to the link I provided you and enter in `Code generator` you have the script.

Comment: I'm a little rusty and would love to help pay

Comment: i have 25000 rows in csv file :(

Comment: @Robi well, if the answer is what you wanted you can help marking it as resolved.

Comment: @Robi community (including me) will be glad to help you if you ask as you did. As more detailed your question is a better answer you will get

Comment: if i have csv fiile widh 25K rows how i can run regex for all rows

Comment: @Robi you can use [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to read the file line by line, within a loop you can parse each line. It is simple you need to read a little or ask more question. Btw, as I said before if my post answered to your question I'll appreciate it to mark it as resolved.